# How can I find a character in a substring of a string in C++?

Tags: c++, string

I have a string `abcda`. I want to search for `a` but just in the substring `bcda` and not the whole string. Is there any ways to do that? Something like:

```
s.find('a',s.begin() + 1, s.end())
```

I could do:

```
string substr = s(s.begin() + 1, s.end();
size_t l = substr.find('a');
```

but this won't return the position in `s` but rather the position in `substr`.

Comment: [This `std::string::find` reference](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/string/basic_string/find) should probably be helpful.

Comment: What reference manual are you using?

Comment: http://www.cplusplus.com/reference/string/string/find/ this one

Comment: Even that reference should have told you what you needed to know. Read about the `pos` argument.

Comment: I think you need [std::find](http://www.cplusplus.com/reference/algorithm/find/) or on a more up-to-date but harder to understand reference [std::find](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/algorithm/find) - if you want to use iterators.

Comment: oh I see. I could just do `s.find('a', s.begin() + 1)` . Thank you everyone for and sorry for asking a silly question.

Comment: @haruhi No, you're mixing the arguments of `std::find()` and `std::string`'s `find()`. Where `std::find` takes iterators, the `std::string` member function `find` takes positions. So it would simply be `s.find('a', 1)`. Or if you want to use `std::find`: `std::find(s.begin() + 1, s.end(), 'a')`.